# Do I have to water Wheat?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

Wheat seems similar to grass in that you use a sickle to cut it, and it has an *absurdly* long grow time, so I was wondering; does wheat grow without water, like grass, or will I have to water it daily like all other plants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately, you do have to water Wheat.  It takes forever to grow, and there's not much you can do about that, beyond using the best field available to you.  For best results, you'll need to water it twice a day, just like any other crop.

There is one advantage in it having such an absurdly long growth period: it gives you more time to fertilize one square of it.  Use the Seed Maker to turn it into seeds, and viola!  You have a bag of high quality seeds.

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo